# Flex: Bubble events from custom classes - non-UI

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I'm trying to find a good way to bubble events up a class tree for none-ui components.

I have a structure like this:

- Controller

  - Unit of Work

    - Child Unit 1 (Raise Event)

I would like to handle the event raised in **Child Unit 1** in the **Controller**.  I've tried to set the bubble property to true but I've read that this only works for UI components.

Is there a way to enable this for custom classes that are not UI components?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bubbling only works if the class is part of a display hierarchy.  Otherwise, how would you tell what the classes parent is?  Even a UIComponent that has not been added tot he stage will not bubble events.

For non UIComponents, you're going to have to listen for, and re-dispatch, the event at each level.